# iphone - Tabbar usage

Tags: iphone, tabbar

Hihi all,

I am trying to make use of tabbar control in my iphone application, I have a few enquiries regarding the control.

1. If i create a tabbar template project, in my application delegate, it loads all the 5 tab controllers during the launch of the application, will this cause any inefficiency of the memory usage?
2. Can I actually drag the tabbar control into each of my screen, and manually switch between screens with [self presentedViewController..] and [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated...]  methods?
3. What is the most efficient way of using tabbar in iphone app?

Thanks in advance!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I'm not sure what 'most efficient' means in your context, I'll try to explain 3. with explaining what  I usually do when it comes to typical tabbar apps:

I don't go with the sample project, because there's so much magic (to me) in all that IB stuff (and I had hard experiences in trying, to combine tabbar controllers and navigation controllers).

I just set up a simple project, get rid of all IB stuff and do something like that in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{    
  NSMutableArray *cons = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

  viewController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
  int i = 0;

  UIViewController *firstController = [[SomeViewViewControllerClazz alloc] init];
  firstController = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Een" image:nil tag:i];
  [cons addObject:firstController];
  [firstController release];
  i++;


  UIViewController *secondController = [[AnotherViewControllerClazz alloc] init];
  secondController = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Twej" image:nil tag:i];
  [cons addObject:secondController];
  [secondController release];
  i++;


  UIViewController *thirdController = [[WhateverViewControllerClazz alloc] init];
  thirdController = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Drej" image:nil tag:i];
  [cons addObject:thirdController];
  [thirdController release];
  i++;

  viewController.viewControllers = cons;
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

That way I've maximum freedom to do whatever I want with the controllers but also have the built in power of tabbars.

1.: That way I never had memory issues even though I load controllers right at the beginning.
2.: If the tabbar idea fits your app, use it as iOs provides it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your enquiries are:

1. No, this will not cause any inefficiency of the memory usage. But you should release tab bar controller
2. You may be do this, But it is not good practice and when you call `presentedViewController` tab will be vanished (sorry for inappropriate term).
3. The most efficient way of using tabbar in iphone app is take a tabbar controller and add that tabBar view.